# Issues with multiple DLL

Tags: c++, oop, dll, com

I have an app that references 2 COM DLL's. There is an Init function in the 2 DLL's that the app invokes on startup.

Both the DLL's are almost similar - except that they have different uid's and different interface names. Apart from that, the logic is the same....and the variables used are also same.

This is how this system works - 
1. StartApp()
2. Init DLL1(appVar1,appVar2)..here the app sets a var x,y defined in this DLL to a value passed from the app. Lets say x = appVar1 and y = appVar2. x and y are global variables.
3. Init DLL2(appVar1a,appVar2a)...the app sets a var x defined in DLL2 to a value passed from the app. x = appVar1a; y = appVar2.

Now when I try to run something on DLL1, the value of x and y has mysteriously changed to something else .

x now becomes appVar2 and y is blank.

Here x, y and all the variables like appVar1, etc passed by the app in the InitDLL function are BSTR's.

I stepped thryu the code...x,y are properly set to appVar1,appVar2 in InitDLL1. But once this function returns and we are initialising the 2nd DLL (InitDLL2), this changes.

Interestingly, I dont see any such issues in DLL2..even though the code/logic is very similar....except the interface it invokes.

In both DLL1 and DLL2, in the InitDLL function, we create a new thread where we use x and y in various functions. Because of the above issue, DLL1 always fails..DLL2 has no issues though.

Any clues on what could b wrong?

Comment: please show the code (both caller and callee are intereseting). You can't assign BSTRs with  =, you need to copy them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assign a BSTR, you need to copy it. Here's the problem:

```
// caller - by COM memory management rules, for [in] parameters
// caller needs to allocate and free the memory
BSTR str = SysAllocString("..."); // string is allocated
comObjectPtr->Init(str);          // in the function, pointer is copied to global
SysFreeString(str);               // string released, pointer points to garbage

// callee
ComObject::Init(BSTR str)
{
    // wrong code!!! you have no idea about lifetime of str,
    // so you can't just assign it. When the caller function
    // exits, string memory is released and your global is thrashed
    // I suspect you use some BSTR wrapper (bstr_t or CComBSTR) so
    // you don't see the deallocation part and that's why the values
    // are invalidated on function exit: the destructor of BSTR wrapper
    // does its job
    global_str = str;             

    // correct code:
    // global_str = SysAllocString(str);
}
```